# Braintree create custom field via api and backup fields via dashboard

Tags: custom-fields, braintree

I would like to add custom fields to braintree from an api and back up the custom fields from the dashboard. Are either of there possible. This would make setting up dev, test, and prod environments much faster.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I work for Braintree.</sub>

Adding and configuring custom fields must be done from the control panel for each environment you are testing.